# Using straing/data from another function

Tags: python

I'm trying to use returned data from one function into multiple other functions. But I don't want the first function to run each time; which is happening in my case.

```
#Function lab
def func_a():
    print('running function a')
    data = 'test'
    return data

def func_b():
    print(func_a())

def func_c():
    print(func_a())

def func_d():
    print(func_a())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_a()
    func_b()
    func_c()
    func_d()
```

Each time that whole function_a runs. But I just want the returned data from "func_a" in other functions.

Comment: IIUC, you just need to remove `func_a()` following `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could alleviate this with a simple class.

I hold the state of the class which runs *func_a* in a variable called *output*. I can then reference this output variable once the class has finished running as much as I like in all other functions without having to re-run func_a.

Hope this helps!

```
class FunctionA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.output = None

    def run_function(self):
        print('running function a')
        data = 'test'
        self.output = data


def func_b():
    print(func_a.output)


def func_c():
    print(func_a.output)


def func_d():
    print(func_a.output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_a = FunctionA()
    func_a.run_function()

    func_b()
    func_c()
    func_d()

>>> running function a
>>> test
>>> test
>>> test
```

Comment: I think that may work. I'll test it out in the morning and update.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but wanted to let you know that using class did exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Not used to using class, something I just started to learn I need to look more into it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome :)
Absolutely classes are great, will open the door to unlocking better ways of writing code!

Answer (score 1):

Your `func_a` does two things. To make this clear, let's call it, `print_and_return_data`.

There are several ways to to break apart the two things `print_and_return_data` does. One way is to split up the two behaviors into smaller sub-methods:

```py
def print_and_return_data():
    print('running function a')  # keeping the old print behavior
    data = 'test'
    return data
```

into:

```py
def print_run():
    print('running function a')  # keeping the old print behavior

def return_data():
    return 'test'

def print_and_return_data():
    print_run()
    return return_data()
```

So that other functions only use what they need:

```py
def func_b():
    print(return_data())
```

Another way is to change `print_and_return_data` to behave differently the first time it's called from the following times it's called (I don't recommend this because functions changing based on how many times it's been called can be confusing):

```py
context = {'has_printed_before': False}

def print_and_return_data():
    if not context['has_printed_before']:
        print('running function a')
        context['has_printed_before'] = True
    data = 'test'
    return data

def func_b():
    print(print_and_return_data())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_a()  # prints
    func_b()  # won't print
```

One way to avoid "functions behaving differently when they're called" is to pass the variation (the "context") in as an argument:

```py
def return_data(also_print=False):
    if also_print:
        print('running function a')
    data = 'test'
    return data

def func_b():
    print(return_data())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_a(also_print=True)  # prints
    func_b()                 # won't print
```

Comment: Thank you, I see what you are saying. So here is the issue (I'll use your example). "def return_data()" runs bunch of scripts and then returns "test".

When I call it in "def func_b()" and/or other function. It will give me the data but it will also re run the whole script before it each time.

Comment: added more alternatives & examples, please take a look